# Filter type String in Clojure

Tags: filter, clojure

Currently I'm trying to learn Clojure and I would like to write a function that has a variable amount of parameters. This function should filter every input to check if it's a string or not. If it does, every input of type string should be returned..

Clojure is hard for me and different way of thinking, but am I on the right direction here.. I can't seem to solve it:

```
(defn returnString [& y]
(if (next y)
(filter (fn [x] (= (type x) "java.lang.String"))y)
(recur (next x))))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a function called `string?` that returns true if the argument is a string, or false if not.

```
=> (string? "hi")
true
=> (string? 100)
false
=> (string? ["a" "b" "c"])
false
```

So with that in mind, your function would look like:

```
(defn return-strings [& vals]
  (filter string? vals))
```

The filter function will return a sequence (essentially a collection) of values, so there is no need worry about recursion (that is, using `recur`) in your custom function for this case.

---

The anonymous function you use to determine what is a string is very close to being correct. If you take a look at the source for `string?` by entering `(source string?)` into your REPL, you'll see:

```
(fn [x] (instance? String x))
```

Although, the approach you are taking would work as well. You just need to specify the String class instead of the string value you were giving. (Note, you can leave off `java.lang` because that package is automatically included just like it is in Java.)

```
(fn [x] (= (type x) String))
```